# How many dice rolls would it take, for an N-sided die, to guess with 99% probability that the number of sides is N?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Thought of this question today when I was looking at the dungeons and dragons dice.

Comment: Great question! You may have a look at the German Tank problem on Wikipedia

Comment: This depends on how you estimate the number of possible outcomes.